# Sorting lines by keyword and group results

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I want to sort links like in desired output, but I have no idea how to change my code

So, how to change code to get my desired output?

Thanks in advance for any help

Code:

```
def my_sort(line):
    social_folders = {'engine': 1,
                    'wormix_mm': 2,
                    'wormix_ok': 3}
    line_fields = line.strip().split("/")
    social = line_fields[3]
    print(line_fields[3])
    return social_folders[social]

numbers = 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'
with open('./testsort.txt') as testsortf, \
     open('./test_out999.txt', "w") as test_out:
    contents = testsortf.readlines()
    contents[-1] = f'{contents[-1]}\n'
    contents.sort(key=my_sort)
    for i, line in enumerate(contents):
        test_out.write(f'{numbers[i]}:\n{line}')
        if i+1 < len(contents):
            test_out.write('\n')
```

My inputs from .txt file:

```
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold3
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold3
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold1
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold4
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold2
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold1
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold2
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold5
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold5
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold1
```

So, inputs without any sorting

Desired output:

```
First:
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold3
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold1
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold2
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold5

Second:
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold2
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold1
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold5

Third:
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold1
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold4
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold3
```

Now output:

```
First:
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold

Second:
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold1

Third:
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold3

Fourth:
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefoldtest
```

Comment: Any example input? for these outputs...

Comment: @SorooshNoorzad , Sorry, edited: I add inputs

Comment: I did it, only to help you. but you should improve your way of asking questions. Comprehend what you exactly want to ask, then go ahead. It's hard to understand other people's code for each question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (I commented what I did, inside the code).

```
def my_sort(conts):
    social_folders = {'engine': 1, 'wormix_mm': 2, 'wormix_ok': 3}
    line_fields = conts.strip().split("/")
    social = line_fields[3]
    return social_folders[social]


# I didn't know what is the differences between First and second section.
# So I put them together. You can handle that yourself.
numbers = 'First', 'Second', 'Third'#, 'Fourth'
folds = ['engine', 'wormix_mm', 'wormix_ok']
with open('./testsort.txt') as testsortf, open('./test_out999.txt', "w") as test_out:
    contents = testsortf.readlines()
    contents[-1] = f'{contents[-1]}\n'
    contents.sort(key=my_sort)
    # It needs 2 for loops
    for k, fold in enumerate(numbers):
        # Put enter before every category, except the first one
        if k != 0:
            test_out.write(f'\n')
        # Put the label of each category
        test_out.write(f'{numbers[k]}:\n')
        for i, line in enumerate(contents):
            # Put the right label in each category
            if line.strip().split("/")[3] == folds[k]:
                test_out.write(f'{line}')
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.groupby()` from the standard library will cluster the list of links the way you want, but it requires a bit of set up.  Specifically, in addition to a sorted iterable of links, it needs to know what part of the link string to group by.  For that, something like a regular expression that isolates the key part of the link is needed.

Example:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

sorted_links = sorted([
    "https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold",
    "https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold3",
    "https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold3",
    "https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold1",
    "https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold4",
    "https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold2",
    "https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold1",
    "https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold2",
    "https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold5",
    "https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold5",
    "https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold1",
])

# Finds the category part of the path that follows the domain name (e.g., "engine")
category = re.compile(r"https.*\.[a-z]{2,3}\/([^\/]*)")

for _, group in groupby(sorted_links, lambda url: category.search(url).group(1)):
    for url in group:
        print(url)
    print()
```

Output:

```
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold1
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold2
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold3
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/somefold5

https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold1
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold2
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/somefold5

https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold1
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold3
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/somefold4
```